# Sieve of Eratosthenes in Python 3

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

> Currently, the code will generate a range of natural numbers from 1 to N and store it in a list. Then the program will iterate through that list, marking each multiple of a prime as 0 and storing each prime in a secondary list.

This is a translation of a TI-Basic program, shown [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104433/ti-basic-sieve-of-eratosthenes-for-prime-generation), so the same description still applies.

Here's an animation:

[image: From Wikipedia]

One of the main optimizations that I want to see implemented would be the actual removal of prime multiples from the list instead of simply setting them to 0. As it is currently written, this would be a challenge to perform without adding in another `if` statement. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
def sieve(end):
    prime_list = []
    sieve_list = list(range(end+1))
    for each_number in range(2,end+1):
        if sieve_list[each_number]:
            prime_list.append(each_number)
            for every_multiple_of_the_prime in range(each_number*2, end+1, each_number):
                sieve_list[every_multiple_of_the_prime] = 0
    return prime_list
```

[Here's a link to PythonTutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+sieve(end%29%3A%0D%0A++++prime_list+%3D+%5B%5D%0D%0A++++sieve_list+%3D+list(range(end%2B1%29%29%0D%0A++++for+each_number+in+range(2,end%2B1%29%3A%0D%0A++++++++if+sieve_list%5Beach_number%5D%3A%0D%0A++++++++++++prime_list.append(each_number%29%0D%0A++++++++++++for+every_multiple_of_the_prime+in+range(each_number*2,+end%2B1,+each_number%29%3A%0D%0A++++++++++++++++sieve_list%5Bevery_multiple_of_the_prime%5D+%3D+0%0D%0A++++return+prime_list%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Asieve(10%29&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=true&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0), which will visualize the code in operation.

Comment: Hey that's a pretty cool animation!

Comment: @Mat'sMug It came from Wikipedia, turns out they have some very enlightening gifs. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a couple things:

```
sieve_list = list(range(end+1))
```

You don't actually need your list to be `[0, 1, 2, ... ]`. You just need an indicator of whether or not it's true or false. So it's simpler just to start with:

```
sieve_list = [True] * (end + 1)
```

That'll likely perform better as well.

When you're iterating over multiples of primes, you're using:

```
range(each_number*2, end+1, each_number)
```

But we can do better than `each_number*2`, we can start at `each_number*each_number`. Every multiple of that prime between it and its square will already have been marked composite (because it will have a factor smaller than `each_number`). That'll save a steadily larger increment of time each iteration.

As an optimization, we know up front that 2 and 3 are primes. So we can start our iteration at `5` and ensure that we only consider `each_number` to not be multiples of 2 or 3. That is, alternate incrementing by 4 and 2. We can write this function:

```
def candidate_range(n):
    cur = 5
    incr = 2
    while cur < n+1:
        yield cur
        cur += incr
        incr ^= 6 # or incr = 6-incr, or however
```

Full solution:

```
def sieve(end):
    prime_list = [2, 3]
    sieve_list = [True] * (end+1)
    for each_number in candidate_range(end):
        if sieve_list[each_number]:
            prime_list.append(each_number)
            for multiple in range(each_number*each_number, end+1, each_number):
                sieve_list[multiple] = False
    return prime_list
```

Impact of various changes with `end` at 1 million, run 10 times:

```
initial solution       6.34s
[True] * n             3.64s (!!)
Square over double     3.01s
candidate_range        2.46s
```

Also, I would consider `every_multiple_of_the_prime` as an unnecessary long variable name, but YMMV.

Comment: These are excellent suggestions, and I will use them. I want to know though, how well do you think the original optimization that I was trying to wrap my head around would have worked?

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the answer that I was looking for.